# Highchart fluid top/bottom margin with Pie chart

Tags: charts, highcharts

I'm trying to display a pia chart like one in the picture:
[image]

I must configure the chart with this code:

```
chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false,
            marginBottom: -180,
            marginTop: -50,
            height: '50%',
        },
```

marginTop and marginBottom are fixed so when I resize the page the result is this:

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered to set the `responsive` options and decrease `marginBottom` and `marginTop` for the smaller window? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive

Comment: The responsive option does not work in continuous way, but based on different threshold. I world like simply to not have margin on top and bottom at all. So the chart can adapt continuously without disapiring.

Comment: Chritian, are you able to reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/gkp8dowL/3/ I create the example. It's not the same but similar behaviour when you try to resize the output box.

Comment: I think that you should leave your margin settings and try to implement something like is done here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7py3mnbe/